# Dynamically change JW Player playlist title

Tags: javascript, api, jwplayer

Within JW Player 6.8, I want to dynamically change the title of the current "source" (playlist) being played. I want, using Ajax, send messages to the user in the player.

I can set the variable:

```
jwplayer().config.playlist[0].title='This song is very cool';
```

But the player still shows the original "title" set in setup.

How can I force JW Player to render the text again, reading the new info? It's an audio streaming (only one element in the playlist array).

Comment: I am fairly sure that the player needs to be reloaded, or the actual file needs to be reloaded with a jwplayer().load() call.

Comment: Agreed with @EthanJWPlayer , you can not change playlist title without `jwplayer.load()` function

Comment: Indeed, that is right.